# Pulling a list of entries from Registry key and checking them for anything that is contained in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, key, registry, uninstallation

I am using the following code to try and pull a list of installed software on a system and check for certain entries within the list, so far I have managed to get the software list to run as desired using the following code:

```
$path = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' 
Get-ChildItem $path | Get-ItemProperty | Select-Object DisplayName
if (ItemProperty -Name -eq ('Wacom Tablet')) { 
  start notepad.exe
}
```

I would like this to be an array that references the `DisplayName` list, but I get the following error:

```
ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wacom Tablet' because it
does not exist.
At C:\Users\username\Documents\Scripts\win10test.ps1:39 char:5
+ if (ItemProperty -Name -eq ('Wacom Tablet')) {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\WINDOWS\system32\Wacom Tablet:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: So you want to start `notepad.exe` if any of the registry keys have the `DisplayName` "Wacom Tablet"?

Comment: Thats just a trigger to test that it's working, this is where it goes afterwards:   
    #if([Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major -EQ 6.0) {
    #installWIN10
    #} elseif([Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major -EQ 6.1) {
    #InstallWin10
    #}
    #} elseif([Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major -EQ 10.0) {
    #Echo "You already have Windows 10 installed, please press any key to exit this program."
    #}
    #Exit

Comment: `if([System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version -lt [version]'10.0'){<# install win10 #>}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemProperty` is expanded to `Get-ItemProperty`, so your `if` condition

```
ItemProperty -Name -eq ('Wacom Tablet')
```

becomes

```
Get-ItemProperty -Name -eq -Path ('Wacom Tablet')
```

meaning that your code is trying to get a property `-eq` from an item `Wacom Tablet` in the current working directory (in your case apparently `C:\WINDOWS\system32`).

What you seem to want to do is something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $path | Get-ItemProperty |
  Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq 'Wacom Tablet'} |
  ForEach-Object {
    # do stuff
  }
```

or like this:

```
$prop = Get-ChildItem $path | Get-ItemProperty |
        Select-Object -Expand DisplayName
if ($prop -eq 'Wacom Tablet') {
  # do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, one other question on topic, within the if statement where I have 'Wacom Tablet', can I extend  this to be an array of items that I need to check for?

Comment: Worked a treat, Thanks ever so much for you assistance :)

Comment: For an array use `-contains` instead of `-eq`.